# Где хранятся индексные файлы репозиториев Linux?

Tags: linux, репозиторий, обновления, gpg, apt

Перед обновлением репозиториев, я удалил ключ от одного из них (вручную из папки `trusted.gpg.d` либо из файла `trusted.gpg`). При попытке выполнить `apt update` получил сообщение:

> Следующие подписи не могут быть проверены, так как недоступен открытый ключ: NO_PUBKEY 4C6E74D6C0A35108
>   W: Произошла ошибка при проверке подписи. Репозиторий не обновлён, и будут использованы предыдущие индексные файлы.

После этого, установить приложение всё ещё возможно. Насколько я понимаю, установится просто старая версия, которая была проверена ещё когда ключ на компьютере был.

Где хранится доверенный список файлов с этого репозитория? Откуда берётся идентификатор `4C6E74D6C0A35108`? Я не нашёл его в файле `Release` в репозитории.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

если взглянуть на репозиторий стабильной ветки дистрибутива *debian gnu/linux*:

```
$ rsync rsync://mirror.yandex.ru/debian/dists/stable/
drwxr-xr-x          4,096 2019/04/27 12:31:23 .
-rw-r--r--      1,984,315 2019/04/27 12:03:52 ChangeLog
lrwxrwxrwx             30 2017/06/17 11:44:51 Release
lrwxrwxrwx             34 2017/06/17 11:44:51 Release.gpg
drwxr-xr-x          4,096 2019/04/27 12:30:44 contrib
drwxr-xr-x          4,096 2019/04/27 12:30:44 main
drwxr-xr-x          4,096 2019/04/27 12:30:44 non-free
```

то увидим файл `Release` и подпись к нему — `Release.gpg`.

содержимое подписи — три сигнатуры. т.е., файл `Release` подписан сразу тремя ключами, с идентификаторами `8B48AD6246925553`, `7638D0442B90D010` и `EF0F382A1A7B6500` (вот они, эти «загадочные идентификаторы»):

```
$ wget -qO - http://mirror.yandex.ru/debian/dists/stable/Release.gpg | gpg --list-packets
# off=0 ctb=89 tag=2 hlen=3 plen=563
:signature packet: algo 1, keyid 8B48AD6246925553
        version 4, created 1556357444, md5len 0, sigclass 0x00
        digest algo 8, begin of digest f0 eb
        hashed subpkt 33 len 21 (issuer fpr v4 A1BD8E9D78F7FE5C3E65D8AF8B48AD6246925553)
        hashed subpkt 2 len 4 (sig created 2019-04-27)
        subpkt 16 len 8 (issuer key ID 8B48AD6246925553)
        data: [4096 bits]
# off=566 ctb=89 tag=2 hlen=3 plen=563
:signature packet: algo 1, keyid 7638D0442B90D010
        version 4, created 1556357444, md5len 0, sigclass 0x00
        digest algo 8, begin of digest e6 a4
        hashed subpkt 33 len 21 (issuer fpr v4 126C0D24BD8A2942CC7DF8AC7638D0442B90D010)
        hashed subpkt 2 len 4 (sig created 2019-04-27)
        subpkt 16 len 8 (issuer key ID 7638D0442B90D010)
        data: [4096 bits]
# off=1132 ctb=89 tag=2 hlen=3 plen=563
:signature packet: algo 1, keyid EF0F382A1A7B6500
        version 4, created 1556357613, md5len 0, sigclass 0x00
        digest algo 8, begin of digest de 48
        hashed subpkt 33 len 21 (issuer fpr v4 067E3C456BAE240ACEE88F6FEF0F382A1A7B6500)
        hashed subpkt 2 len 4 (sig created 2019-04-27)
        subpkt 16 len 8 (issuer key ID EF0F382A1A7B6500)
        data: [4096 bits]
```

например, вот публичная часть третьего из этих ключей (видите тот самый идентификатор `EF0F382A1A7B6500`?):

```
$ gpg --keyid-format long /etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/debian-archive-stretch-stable.gpg 2>/dev/null | grep pub
pub   rsa4096/EF0F382A1A7B6500 2017-05-20 [SC] [expires: 2025-05-18]
```

благодаря наличию публичной части ключа в одном из файлов `/etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/*.gpg`, мы можем доверять этой подписи.

---

содержимое самого подписанного файла (`Release`) — это хэш-суммы и размеры «служебных» файлов репозитория. большей частью — списков пакетов. например:

```
$ wget -qO - http://mirror.yandex.ru/debian/dists/stable/Release | sed -n 60p
 8cebafcf8941b37fe32917320b8c2ef4    61114 contrib/binary-amd64/Packages.gz
```

пример описания пакета в таком файле:

```
$ wget -qO - http://mirror.yandex.ru/debian/dists/stable/contrib/binary-amd64/Packages.gz |gunzip | head -n 20
Package: alien-arena
Version: 7.66+dfsg-3
Installed-Size: 2067
Maintainer: Debian Games Team <pkg-games-devel@lists.alioth.debian.org>
Architecture: amd64
Depends: libc6 (>= 2.17), libcurl3-gnutls (>= 7.16.2), libfreetype6 (>= 2.3.5), libgcc1 (>= 1:3.0), libjpeg62-turbo (>= 1.3.1), libogg0 (>= 1.0rc3), libstdc++6 (>= 4.1.1), libvorbis0a (>= 1.1.2), libvorbisfile3 (>= 1.1.2), libx11-6, libxxf86vm1, zlib1g (>= 1:1.1.4), libopenal1, alien-arena-data
Description: Standalone 3D first person online deathmatch shooter
Homepage: http://red.planetarena.org
Description-md5: de2b3d0db5845c79b22ffc0c38842f1b
Tag: game::fps, hardware::input:keyboard, hardware::input:mouse,
 hardware::opengl, implemented-in::c, interface::3d,
 interface::graphical, interface::x11, network::client, role::program,
 uitoolkit::sdl, use::gameplaying, x11::application
Section: contrib/games
Priority: extra
Filename: pool/contrib/a/alien-arena/alien-arena_7.66+dfsg-3_amd64.deb
Size: 774388
MD5sum: d54108f51edd8ad9d147da8261e0473f
SHA256: 4c58933e396ba5977dade1318a3f0545a5a98283b87a8bbe5eecd2a5ccc5ec8a
```

про пакет, как видите, тоже есть информация и о размере файла, и о его хэш-суммах.

---

таким образом, файл `Release.gpg` удостоверяет:

1. подлинность списка «служебных файлов» (`Release`)
2. благодаря наличию в этом списке размеров и хэш-сумм файлов со списками пакетов — удостоверяет и подлинность списков пакетов (например, `contrib/binary-amd64/Packages.gz`)
3. а благодаря наличию в этих списках пакетов хэш-сумм и размеров файлов с пакетами, удостоверяет и сами файлы с пакетами (например, `pool/contrib/a/alien-arena/alien-arena_7.66+dfsg-3_amd64.deb`)

вы скачиваете файл с пакетом, проверяете его размер и вычисляете хэш-сумму от содержимого, и если всё сошлось, значит, пакет подлинный.

---

ах, да, на заголовок вопроса и не ответил.

> Где хранятся индексные файлы репозиториев Linux?

там же, в репозитории, и хранятся. надеюсь, получилось это продемонстрировать достаточно наглядно и понятно. если неясно — спрашивайте, дополню ответ (тем, что знаю).

чтобы не скачивать все перечисленные выше файлы каждый раз при вызове программы *apt*, они кэшируются. по умолчанию — в каталоге `/var/lib/apt/lists/`.

Comment: Очень подробный ответ, большое спасибо! Только одного так и не усвоил - где локальный компьютер хранит информацию о том, что старый список пакетов уже был проверен, и ему можно доверять? Я ведь удалил сторонние ключи из системы, но последнюю замеченную при наличии ключа версию могу поставить, хотя самого ключа уже нет.

Comment: На соседнем стаке подсказали, что последние успешно проверенные списки хранятся в /var/lib/apt/lists.

Comment: там те списки, которые скачаны. а проверка при каждом вызове `apt install` каждый раз проходит заново. у вас она не прошла — о чём вам *apt* и сообщил.

Comment: дополнил ответ. файлы кэшируются, но это не влияет на процедуру проверки. вы можете очистить упомянутый каталог — они будут скачаны заново. но т.к. ключ, которым подписан `release`, неизвестен, так и будете получать предупреждение.

Comment: Не совсем так, из предупреждения исчезнет сообщение об использовании старых индексных файлов. Если очистить каталог, то без ключа туда ничего заново не скачается, ведь проверка не будет проходить. Так что и старую версию пакета установить тоже не выйдет.

Comment: согласен, я не совсем корректно изложил. по умолчанию не будет скачиваться ничего. это изменяется настройками *apt* или разово — опцией `--allow-insecure-repositories`. и поставить пакет можно — всего лишь ответить «да» на соответствующий вопрос.